# Is there a way to group specific sequences in a string in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to automatically find and replace a series of numbers in a string in Python. How would I do this?

For context, I am writing a program that will automate the FreshDirect ordering process here at work. I am using BeautifulSoup in conjuction with Selenium to make a program that will automatically click the appropriate elements to add or take away from the standing inventory list. In order for selenium to find the appropriate button element for the item on my list, I am using BeautifulSoup to scrape for the unique item ID and then I want to place that unique ID in the button element line in order for that button to be found and clicked. Because I'm working on it in pieces I will give an example.

```
import re

s = 'button id="qty_plus_cartline_change_1221067058" type="button"class="quantity_plus " data-component="quantitybox.inc">+<span class="offscreen">Increase the Quantity 1</span></button'

new_string = re.sub('\d', 'new_number', s)

print(new_string)
```

Now I've tried a variety of ways and this is the closest. I need to replace that number next to cartline_change. Using this code, it replaces that number but it also replaces the 1 next to Increase the Quantity. For selenium to work, it cannot replace that 1. Is there code that will enable me to replace that unique id number and not the 1?

Comment: `new_string = re.sub('qty_plus_cartline_change_\d+', 'qty_plus_cartline_change_new_number', s)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, You were on the right track! Just need to change the regex to '\d+' from '\d' and add count as 1.

```
s = 'button id="qty_plus_cartline_change_1221067058" type="button"class="quantity_plus " data-component="quantitybox.inc">+<span class="offscreen">Increase the Quantity 1</span></button'
new_string = re.sub('\d+', 'new_number', s,1)
print(new_string)
```

Comment: Thank you! I greatly appreciate it. I thought it would be something of that sort but I couldn't get my finger on it. Blessings.

Answer (score 2):

First, use `\d+` to match the whole group of digits instead of individual ones. Then, you can use the `count=` argument of `re.sub` to limit to 1 replacement:

```
import re

s = 'button id="qty_plus_cartline_change_1221067058" type="button"class="quantity_plus " data-component="quantitybox.inc">+<span class="offscreen">Increase the Quantity 1</span></button'

new_string = re.sub(r'\d+', 'new_number', s, count=1)

print(new_string)

# button id="qty_plus_cartline_change_new_number" type="button"class="quantity_plus " data-component="quantitybox.inc">+<span class="offscreen">Increase the Quantity 1</span></button
```